# how to remove leading first zero only from a mobile number input box

Tags: jquery, regex

```
// Code for mobile number's leading zeros removal on submit of form
mobNumberBefore = $('#mobilePhone').val();
mobNumberAfter = mobNumberBefore.replace(/^0+/,'');
$('#mobilePhone').val(mobNumberAfter);
```

By this code all starting zeros are being gone,

suppose 0911223322 then it will become 911223322 that's good
suppose 00911223322 then it will become 911223322 that's not good i want it to be 0911223322

means only first zero should be removed.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/awL5d92a/1/

Answer (score 1):

remove `+` from regular expression

try

```
mobNumberAfter = mobNumberBefore.replace(/^0/,'');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.substring()`.

Check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shrinivas93/bpa5oepx/).

```js
$('#button').click(function() {
  var number = $('#number').val();
  if (number.startsWith('0'))
    number = number.substring(1);
  alert(number);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' id='number' />
<br>
<input type='button' id='button' value='Check' />
```